# Is there a way to hide branches on Github?

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I'm looking for a way to hide branches on github, is there possible?
For example: I'm the repository owner and I want to have three contributors, that can't merge on main, but they can open a PR and they can't see others branches, just their own branches and main.
I need this to a specific repository.

Does anyone knows a way to do this? Github actions or something like that?

I know this could be controversial, but...

Thank you! :D

Comment: I believe they can create private forks

Comment: If one has access to a Git repo, he/she can see all branches. Your only hope is to force all other contributors to stay in their own repos (forks) so they won't see each others' branches. But if their forks are on GitHub, anyway the branches are still publicly visible/discoverable. Git emphasizes on sharing, so I wonder why you want to use Git if sharing is not one of your goals.